# Автоматизация Desktop приложений (связка WinForms + jar)

Tags: c#, winforms, test-automation

Здравствуйте!
Суть проекта такая:
Есть приложение WinForms, которое выступает слушателем jar приложений. Т.е.

1. Запускам winform
2. Запускаем jar
3. Активируем сервис
4. Действия, которые мы выполняем в jar приложении пишутся в лог и отображаются в winforms (см скрин: http://joxi.net/8Anbln3tq15xVA)

Собственно, вопрос. Какие средства можно использовать для автоматизации в данном проекте?
Насколько я понимаю, то Coded UI не подходит в силу того, что дополнительно используются jar приложения.
Прошу помочь, пожалуйста

PS. Для автоматизации использую c#.